# Windows Defenders - Antimalware - Exclude Directory from Scan

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-defender

I looked at this article: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-exclude-files-and-folders-windows-defender-antivirus-scans, but my Windows 2019 Datacenter server server doesn't look anything like there screen shot.

On my system it looks like this, and all the settings seem to related to firewall as opposed to the anti-virus malware scanner.  I'm writing out some rolling log files from an application, and I'm think they are causing "Antimalware Service Executable" to go to 15% of CPU.

On my system it looks like this (and I've tried the "Advanced Settings", but they looked like firewall settings).

[image]

Comment: Well... you're looking at the Windows Defender Firewall. Instead, go to Settings>Update & Security>Windows Security>Virus & threat protection.

Comment: Thanks, I will add screen shots in answer.  Do you have to restart after making changes?

Comment: No, you do not need to reboot after adding exclusions.